# A basic question on converges in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, metric-spaces, weak-convergence

The distance $d(F,G)$ between two distribution functions is the infimum of those $\epsilon > 0$ such that $G(x-\epsilon) - \epsilon \leq F(x) \leq G(x+\epsilon) + \epsilon \quad\forall x $. Now I want to show that if a sequence of distribution functions $\{F_n\}$ converge to a distribution function $F$ in weak sense (only at continuity points) then $d(F_n,F) \to 0$.

Proof: We choose continuity points $x_i$ of $F$ in such a way that $x_0 < x_1 < \dots < x_k, F(x_0)<\epsilon, F(x_k) > 1- \epsilon$ and $x_i - x_{i-1} < \epsilon$. Then I am able to show that if $x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_{i}$ then we can find an $n_0$ such that for all $n \geq n_0$  $d(F_n,F) =0.$. But stuck in the cases where $x\leq x_0$ and $x \geq x_k$. Any solution/hint will be helpful.